# Mobius transformation mapping the upper half plane to itself different approach

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

I am trying to use the fact that every bi- holomorphic function from the unit disk to itself can be writen as $$
\varphi(z)=\frac{\lambda(z-a)}{1-\bar{a} z}
$$ for every $a,\lambda \in D_1(0)$ to show that mobius transformation from the upper half plane $\{z:\mathrm{Im}(z) > 0\}$ to iteself can be written as $$f(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$ s.t $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$

How do I use $\varphi(z)$ for that? not sure how do I solve it without 3 system of equations

Comment: Take your map and left and right compose with maps into the unit disk. You'll end up decomposing your map $\mathbb H \to \mathbb H$ into a sequence $\mathbb H \to \mathbb D \to \mathbb D \to \mathbb H$. The first and last maps are canonical, and the middle map must be of the form $\varphi$. Do some algebra, and you're done

Comment: not  sure how i get $\mathbb H \to \mathbb D \to \mathbb D \to \mathbb H$ by writing $\varphi o f o \varphi$

Comment: @Sagigever: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform#Complex_homography